# RMI java UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return;

Tags: java, intellij-idea, исключения, rmi

Запускаю из idea Сервер

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, InterruptedException
    {

        CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService();
        ICustomerService stub = (ICustomerService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(customerService, 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        registry.rebind("CustomerService", stub);

        //HibernateSessionFactory.shutdown();
    }
```

Потом клиент

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException
    {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        ICustomerService stub = (ICustomerService) registry.lookup("CustomerService");
        stub.addNewCustomer("TESTRMI", "TEST", null, null);
    }
```

Вылетает Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: service.interfaces.ICustomerService (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at Client.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: service.interfaces.ICustomerService (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:556)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:311)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в ошибке написано, что необходимо сделать - добавьте Security Manager.

```
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
```

Comment: Где-то читал , что он нужен только для приложений с шифрованием , да и среда его подсвечивает как depricated

Comment: если вы добавите в вопрос [mcve] - это сильно облегчит ответ на него